# Joins and SUMS?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi Have the tables below:
teams, teamPoints, team_members, pointsTable
I'm trying to SUM team member points and then SUM the team points:

```
Teams
|TeamID |TeamName  | TeamLocation|
 -------------------------------
|1      | sm1        | location1|
|2      | sm2        | location2|


TeamPoints
|TeamID |TotalPonts  | RemainderPonts|
 -------------------------------
|1      | 10         | 7            |
|1      | 8          | 6            |
|2      | 8          | 6            |


team_members
|TeamID |UserID  | 
 -----------------
|1      | 1      | 
|1      | 2      |
|2      | 3      |  


pointsTable
|UserID |TotalPonts  | RemainderPonts|
 -------------------------------
|1      | 10         | 7            |
|2      | 8          | 6            |
|2      | 8          | 6            |


so results for team sm1 (TeamID =1) should be

TeamName=sm1,TeamPoints.TotalPonts =18, TeamPoints.RemainderPonts=13
pointsTable.TotalPonts =26, pointsTable.RemainderPonts=19
```

this works to sum the members points but having trouble with the team points

```
SELECT 
    teams.TeamID AS theTeamID,
    teams.TeamName,
    teams.TeamLocation,
    team_members.TeamID,
    team_members.UserID,
    SUM(pointstable.RemainderPoints) AS points
FROM
    teams
        LEFT JOIN
    team_members ON teams.TeamID = team_members.TeamID
        LEFT JOIN
    pointstable ON team_members.UserID = pointstable.UserID
GROUP BY teams.TeamID
```

have tried

```
SELECT 
    teams.TeamID AS theTeamID,
    teams.TeamName,
    teams.TeamLocation,
    team_members.TeamID,
    team_members.UserID,
    SUM(pointstable.RemainderPoints) AS points,
    teampoints.TeamID AS tpID,
    SUM(teampoints.TotalPoints) AS teamRedeamable
FROM
    teams
        LEFT JOIN
    team_members ON teams.TeamID = team_members.TeamID
        LEFT JOIN
    pointstable ON team_members.UserID = pointstable.UserID
        LEFT JOIN
    teampoints ON teams.TeamID = teampoints.TeamID
GROUP BY teams.TeamID
```

But seems to change/multiply original values
Have also tried subselects but need to some how group??

Any help is welcomed

Comment: are you summing all points of the team or also with the team member? are you forgetting to `group by teams.TeamID, team_members.UserID`

Comment: need to sum all points for that team so, if 3 members and each have 5 points total is 15, if I group by UserID it creates too many records, i just need 1 record per team

Comment: group by everything from teams except the team points, leave that in the sum, remove everything from team_members in the select.  as long as you have that team member info in there, you're going to get a record for each member.... if you need that information, join that with the result of your group by query.

Comment: @Roy,  `SUM(pointstable.RemainderPoints) AS points` not `SUM(pointstable.TotalPionts) AS points,` for your members point?

Comment: tried your suggestion gloomy.penguin but not sure if I got right, I used the second bit of code above, took out team_members in the select and grouped by teams.TeamID, teams.TeamName, teams.TeamLocation but the same results the problem I'm having is the SUM(pointstable.RemainderPoints) and  SUM(teampoints.TotalPoints) give incorrect results when I include the 3rd left join join

Comment: Any one have any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need a subselect to get the details from the user points table, and join this against the main table:-

```
SELECT 
    teams.TeamID AS theTeamID,
    teams.TeamName,
    teams.TeamLocation,
    SUM(pointstable.RemainderPoints) AS RemainderPonts,
    SUM(pointstable.TotalPonts ) AS TotalPonts,
    Sub1.UserTotalPoints, 
    Sub1.UserRemainderPoints,
    Sub2.TeamTotalPoints,
    Sub2.TeamRemainderPoints
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN team_members ON teams.TeamID = team_members.TeamID
LEFT JOIN pointstable ON team_members.UserID = pointstable.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT TeamID, SUM(TotalPoints) AS UserTotalPoints, SUM(RemainderPoints) AS UserRemainderPoints
    FROM team_members
    INNER JOIN pointsTable
    ON team_members.UserID = pointsTable.UserID
    GROUP BY TeamID
) Sub1
ON Sub1.TeamID = teams.TeamID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT TeamID, SUM(TotalPoints) AS TeamTotalPoints, SUM(RemainderPoints) AS TeamRemainderPoints
    FROM TeamPoints
    GROUP BY TeamID
) Sub2
ON Sub0.theTeamID = Sub2.TeamID
GROUP BY teams.TeamID, teams.TeamName, teams.TeamLocation
```

Note that this is slightly dodgy as it has non aggregate columns in the SELECT which are not in the GROUP BY clause. In this case with default MySQL settings this should be fine, but if using a different db (or depending on MySQL settings) you might have to do it as 2 different subselects and join the results together.

```
SELECT Sub0.theTeamID, Sub0.TeamName, Sub0.TeamLocation, Sub0.RemainderPonts, Sub0.TotalPonts, Sub1.UserTotalPoints, Sub1.UserRemainderPoints, Sub2.TeamTotalPoints, Sub2.TeamRemainderPoints
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        teams.TeamID AS theTeamID,
        teams.TeamName,
        teams.TeamLocation,
        SUM(pointstable.RemainderPoints) AS RemainderPonts,
        SUM(pointstable.TotalPonts ) AS TotalPonts
    FROM teams
    LEFT OUTER JOIN team_members ON teams.TeamID = team_members.TeamID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pointstable ON team_members.UserID = pointstable.UserID
) Sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT TeamID, SUM(TotalPoints) AS UserTotalPoints, SUM(RemainderPoints) AS UserRemainderPoints
    FROM team_members
    INNER JOIN pointsTable
    ON team_members.UserID = pointsTable.UserID
    GROUP BY TeamID
) Sub1
ON Sub0.theTeamID = Sub1.TeamID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT TeamID, SUM(TotalPoints) AS TeamTotalPoints, SUM(RemainderPoints) AS TeamRemainderPoints
    FROM TeamPoints
    GROUP BY TeamID
) Sub2
ON Sub0.theTeamID = Sub2.TeamID
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I ran the query but noticed that it is summing from the points table only, I need to sum the teampoints.TotalPoints, as per my second code block, I tried to edit your code to do this, but haven't gotten it to work yet, will keep trying

Comment: Have edited the code to add those counts, although not tested it. Hope that helps